# Writing to /dev/stdout as a file fails with Errno::EACCES when stdout is redirected

Tags: ruby, io, stdout

I have a legacy gem I'm using that, given a filename, knows how to write to a file, but doesn't know how to write to stdout or any other form of IO. So as to make it more flexible, I'm trying to trick it into writing to stdout by passing `/dev/stdout` as the filename. This works, if I run the code that calls the gem in the terminal, and don't redirect the output. But if I then try to redirect the output to a different file or device, it fails with `Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /dev/stdout (Errno::EACCES)`.

After some experimentation and some digging around in the gem's source code, I came up with the following way to reproduce the problem. Given this Ruby script `stdout.rb`:

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

File.open('/dev/stdout', 'w+') do |f|
  f.puts('Hello, world')
end
```

(In this example I'm opening the file `w+` because that's what the legacy gem does, but it fails the same way with `a+`.)

I can run the script in the terminal, and it works:

```sh
$ ./stdout.rb
Hello, world
```

But if I redirect it to a file, pipe it to another command (e.g. `grep`), or try to capture the output with something like `echo $(./stdout.rb)`, it fails:

```sh
$ ./stdout.rb > /tmp/hello.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from ./stdout.rb:3:in `<main>'
        1: from ./stdout.rb:3:in `open'
./stdout.rb:3:in `initialize': Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /dev/stdout (Errno::EACCES)
```

It appears to be failing in the `File.open()` call. But what is different about `/dev/stdout` permissions in the redirect/capture case from when it's just writing to the terminal?

(FWIW, this is on macOS Catalina 10.15.5, Darwin 19.5.0.)

---

**Update:** If I change the mode from `w+` to `w`, it works. I understand from the [IEEE spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fopen.html) that '+' signifies "update", i.e. both reading and writing. It's unclear to me why the legacy gem thinks it needs that, but more importantly, why is this possible in a TTY but not when redirected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is in Ruby `IO::new` [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/IO.html#method-c-new).

> When the open mode of original IO is read only, the mode cannot be changed to be writable. Similarly, the open mode cannot be changed from write only to readable.
> When such a change is attempted the error is raised in different locations according to the platform.

Open the `IO` object with `w` means:

> "w"  Write-only, truncates existing file
> to zero length or creates a new file for writing.

Open the `IO` object with `w+` means:

> "w+" Read-write, truncates existing file to zero length
> or creates a new file for reading and writing.

The problem seems to be that you cannot open `stdout` with `w+` because permission is for `write only`.
The question is why the error is raised only when you use output redirection.

The answer could be in the previous statement I quoted:

> When such a change is attempted the error is raised in different locations according to the platform.

I would suggest using an object of `StringIO` in the [Standard Library](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/StringIO.html) instead of `/dev/stdout` for your 'experiments'.

Added after comment

I realize now that you need to pass a string.

In this case, I would try '/dev/tty', I think it could work because it is not already opened with just writing permission.

The problem is that then you should use a proper `tty` not an emulated terminal inside a GUI to see the result,  or you should find a way to pipe the `tty` output to another `IO`. More important only for `Unix` like `OS`.

Comment: Believe me, if the API took an IO object I would be using StringIO. I may have no recourse but to monkey-patch the method that calls `File.open()`.

Comment: @David Moles ok I realized now that you need to pass a string in some way I updated my answer according to your comment.